# Remember TextView size after changing it with Shared Preferences

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a songbook app, and I want to be able to zoom in and out the lyrics of songs. I added zoom functions but I want the app to be able to remember what text size the lyrics had before the user left the app. I tried using Shared Preferences but it isn't working.

Here is what I tried so far

```kotlin
class Cantare : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var tvSizePrefs: SharedPreferences
    lateinit var tvSizeEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor
    var mTextSize: Float = 50f

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.cantare)

        tvSizePrefs = getSharedPreferences("TextSizePref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        tvSizeEditor = tvSizePrefs.edit()

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar2))
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        val songTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.songTitle)
        val songString = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.songString)

        songString.textSize = tvSizePrefs.getFloat("TextSize", 50f)

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_song, menu)


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        val id: Int = item.itemId

        when(id) {
            R.id.zoomOut -> {
                mTextSize -= 2f
                songString.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (mTextSize))
                tvSizeEditor.putFloat("TextSize", mTextSize)
                tvSizeEditor.apply()
                Toast.makeText(this, songString.textSize.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.zoomIn -> {
                mTextSize += 2f
                songString.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (mTextSize))
                tvSizeEditor.putFloat("TextSize", mTextSize)
                tvSizeEditor.apply()
                Toast.makeText(this, songString.textSize.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your code running or will it not compile? Because the sample you provided doesn't show you defining `songString` in `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: Hi! It does compile except that I didn't provide the full code. Do you want the full code?

Comment: Looks like you have accepted an answer so I presume you don't need any more help?

Comment: Yes I fixed the problem. Still thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problem with your code. 
First one is the `mTextSize` always gets initialized with `50f` and you are not setting its value from saved text size value. Only set the size of your text view inside `onCreate`. So `mTextSize` always starts from `50f` and when you zoom in/out for the first time, size of the texts resets back to ~`50f`.
The second one is you are not passing complex unit when setting text view's size in your `onCreate`. 
I think changing your code to something like this will solve your problem:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    // replace songString.textSize = tvSizePrefs.getFloat("TextSize", 50f) with:
    mTextSize = tvSizePrefs.getFloat("TextSize", 50f)
    text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mTextSize)
    // ...
}
```